# laravel how do i access the data in a one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, one-to-many

ive got a one to many relationship between my model Project and Task. i dont know how i can access the data from the tasks table via the data from my project table. i tried to access the name of the tasks via `{{$projects->task->taskname}}` and such but it wont let me. im basically trying to display all projects with all their tasks in my view

my tables look like following

tasks:
id | project_id | taskname | description | timeestimated | taskstatus | created_at | updated_at

projects:
id | projectname | projectnamenospace | projectdescription | created_at | updated_at

my models:

Task:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'taskname',
        'description',
        'tasktext',
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function comment(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }

}
```

Project:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function task(){
        return $this->hasMany(App::class);
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Project $project)
    {
        $ldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $projects = Project::all();

        $username = Auth::user()->name;
        return view('dashboard', ['user' => $username, 'ldate' => $ldate, 'projects' => $projects]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `{{$projects->task->taskname}}` try single `{{$project->task->taskname}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume in your `dashboard.blade.php` file. You are passing multiple projects and each project has many tasks so you have to run two loops

```
@foreach($projects as $key=>$project)
    @foreach($project->task as $taskRow)
        {{$taskRow->taskname}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

and change in project model

```
public function task(){
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Comment: i tried to run that, it told me that Class App\App not found and yes im trying to output every project with all their tasks, sorry for not telling :)

Comment: in project model replace App::class to Task::class or what you have table for task...I updated my answer

Comment: ah didnt notice i wrote App:class, it seems to work now cheers mate! :D